# Firmware Password Lock after Bootcamp Install

Tags: macos, bootcamp, password, recovery, firmware

Tried to install Windows via Bootcamp on my computer yesterday. When the computer restarted to try and boot on the Windows partition, I got hit with the Firmware Password. Asked my IT guy what it was and the password doesn't work. Either he remembers it wrong or entered it with a typo.

In any case, I've tried every operations i've heard people discuss to try and boot on my main system. Tried booting in Recovery Mode, tried Resetting NVRAM, tried Resetting SMC. Any combinations I try end up on the lock screen of death.

Shouldn't I still be able to boot to recovery or at least select my startup disc?

Answer (score 1):

No - Firmware Passwords exist to prevent any non-approved boot methods and prevent you from bringing any other boot to the system.

It's like putting superglue in a deadbolt lock and only having the small lock on the handle. If the small handle (your normal OS) breaks - you can't get in by bringing another small handle - you need to release the deadbolt (firmware password).

Open a case with Apple Support to see if your firmware lock can be bypassed locally or you need to prove you own the Mac and have apple generate a rescue key.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455

> A firmware password prevents starting up from any internal or external storage device other than the startup disk you've selected.